# Nuxt.js: importing `vuex` emits eslint(import/no-extraneous-dependencies) error

Tags: eslint, nuxt.js

`Nuxt.js` is shipped with `vuex` as dependency so importing it doesn't require me to specify it in `package.json`.

But as `vuex` is not in `package.json`, whenever I try to import `vuex`, `eslint` emits `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` error.

In this case, how can I tell `eslint` to `vuex` is already included in `nuxt` module? Or is there any workaround to ignore some modules, ie. `vuex`, `vue`...

Below is my current `eslint` rules.

```
// .eslintrc.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    'plugin:vue-types/strongly-recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    '@vue/prettier'
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['prettier', 'vue'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'error',
    'no-console': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'import/no-unresolved': 0,
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can specify `vuex` as `core-modules`.
[reference](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/README.md#importcore-modules)

```
// .eslintrc.js
settings: {
  'import/core-modules': ['vue', 'vuex'] // these modules are included in nuxt.js
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore these modules as following:

```
    'node/no-extraneous-import': [
      'error',
      {
        allowModules: ['vue', 'vuex']
      }
    ]
```